# Identify a subset of a range using TRUE statements

Tags: excel, subset

I am attempting to identify a subset of a range based on TRUE FALSE statements. An example is in the following chart below.

```
FALSE   FALSE   1.21147
TRUE    FALSE   1.20984
FALSE   FALSE   1.21083
FALSE   FALSE   1.210315
FALSE   TRUE    1.21151
FALSE   FALSE   1.21335
FALSE   FALSE   1.213515
FALSE   FALSE   1.212435
TRUE    FALSE   1.212125
FALSE   FALSE   1.21226
```

In this scenario I want a subset to be identified based on alternating TRUE statements. In the left side column the first TRUE statement would trigger the beginning of the subset an the TRUE statement in the second column would trigger the end of the subset. I then want to use a simple max function to identify the MAX in the third column. I would use an IF statement to determine whether or not the first TRUE statement is correct however, i am unable to figure out how to identify the subset of the range based on the TRUE statement in the second column. I also want to know whether or not this works from going from the top to the bottom if the statement could possible work going the bottom to the top. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1** can be done using a combination of `MATCH`, `OFFSET` and `MAX`

For this example I've assumed your data is located starting at cell `A2`.

For the sake of clarity I use some intermediate results in cells `E1:E4`.  If you prefer a single formula, simply merge the intermediate formula into the final formula

Cell `E2` = position of first `TRUE` in column `A`

```
=MATCH(TRUE,A2:A11,0)
```

Cell `E3` = position of first `TRUE` in column `B`

```
=MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11,0)
```

Result formula, Max value in column `C` between the rows found in  `E2` and `E3` (inclusive)

```
=MAX(OFFSET($C$1,E2,0,E3-E2+1,1))
```

**Part 2** is more tricky:  I don't think you can search *up* a range for a value.  However, looking at your data it may be OK to search down for the *second* `TRUE`?  If this is OK then:

Cell `E4` = position of second `TRUE` in column `A`

```
=MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(A2:A11,E2,0),0)
```

Or this, entered as an array formula (Insipred by Barry) which *will* get the last `TRUE` in the column

```
=MATCH(2, 1/(A2:A11=TRUE),1)
```

Result formula, Max value in column `C` between the rows found in `E3` and `E4` (inclusive)

```
=MAX(OFFSET($C$1,E3,0,E4+E2-E3+1,1))
```

Comment: To find the position of last TRUE try =MATCH(2, 1/(A2:A11=TRUE)), array entered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen This worked perfectly thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

your part about traversing the table from the bottom up confused me, and also don't know if you can have more than one subset, since you're penultimate row seems to be the opening of a new subset that is not closed. Anyway, hope that this helps. I'm assuming you don't want to use macros, in which case it would be trivial. What you can do is pad the top of the data set with an row that contains FALSE, FALSE, 0, 0, and add this formula to a fourth column starting with the first row of your set:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(A2),NOT(B2),OR(D1=0,AND(NOT(A1),B1))),0,C1)
```

That's assuming that your first row is row 2, and row 1 is used for the padding. A, B, and C are the three columns in your example, and D will print the value of the third column if it's within a subset, or zero if is not, so that you can easily calculate max() or whatever you want to do. I looks like this:

[image]